# Read data from a file into an array - C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to read the data from my input file

```
70 95 62 88 90 85 75 79 50 80 82 88 81 93 75 78 62 55 89 94 73 82
```

and store each value in an array. There's more to this particular problem (the other functions are commented out for now) but this is what's really giving me trouble. I looked for hours at the previous question about data and arrays but I can't find where I'm making the mistake.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 22;
int grades[SIZE];

void readData() {

    int i = 0;
    int grades[i];

    string inFileName = "grades.txt";
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    if (inFile.is_open())  
    {
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
        {
            inFile >> grades[i];
            cout << grades[i] << " ";
        }

        inFile.close(); // CLose input file
    }
    else { //Error message
        cerr << "Can't find input file " << inFileName << endl;
    }
}
/*
    double getAverage() {

        return 0;
    }

    void printGradesTable() {

    }

    void printGradesInRow() {

    }


    void min () {
        int pos = 0;
        int minimum = grades[pos];

        cout << "Minimum " << minimum << " at position " << pos << endl;
    }

    void max () {
        int pos = 0;
        int maximum = grades[pos];

        cout << "Maximum " << maximum << " at position " << pos << endl;
    }

    void sort() {

    }
*/


int main ()
{
    readData();
    return 0;
}
```

and here's my output:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `x[i]` -- I'm looking, but I don't see where `x` is declared.  Which probably means you hastily just typed in code instead of copying and pasting your actual program in the edit window.

Comment: You are reading the data in $x$, but where did you declear $x$

Comment: This code does not compile. How do you expect it to run? `prog.cpp:25:23: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Also, `int grades[i];` -- what is that line supposed to do?

Comment: I understand. I edited it. Can we disregard that? I've copying and pasting and editing. I must've missed the     x[]

Comment: You are using `C++` is there a reason you are not using `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes. I'm not allowed to use vectors. This is for my C++ lab. @PhotometricStereo

Comment: @dev_P `int grades[i];` -- Again, explain what that line does or what you expected it to do.  It isn't even valid C++ syntax, let alone `i` is 0 when the line is executed.

Comment: Hi again, I just wanted to point out that making sure that encoding is set at "Western Windows 1" if you're creating a plain text for your input file on Mac when using the Textedit app. That was why I couldn't get any right. No matter what code I used, I kept picking up zeroes instead the contents of my input file. I noticed it when I decided to recreate the input file on Windows and run my code on Windows and my Mac. 
Thanks for the tips to you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're declaring a local `grades` array with a size of 1, hiding the global `grades` array.  Not only that, you are now accessing the array beyond the bounds, since the local `grades` array can only hold 1 item.

So get rid of the line:

```
int grades[i];
```

However, it needs to be mentioned that this:

```
int i = 0;
int grades[i];
```

is not valid C++ syntax.  You just stumbled into this by mistake, but that code would not compile if compiled using a strict ANSI C++ compiler.

An array in C++ must be declared using a constant expression to denote the number of entries in the array, not a variable.  You, by accident, are using a non-standard compiler extension called *Variable Length Arrays* or VLA's for short.

If this is for a school assignment, do not declare arrays this way (even if you meant to do it), as it is not officially C++.  If you want to declare a dynamic array, that is what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: I don't know but for what reason most of the colleges or universities are making the student to use old c++ style when there are more better alternatives are available

Comment: Thank you PaulMcKenzie. Is there a way use to store data in an array without the use of vectors. Is there a way for you to fix my code? I'm still getting all zeroes if I compile the code that @HariomSingh edited. I tried this on both a Mac and Windows computer

Comment: fix your own code @dev_P

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issue in reading the file , you have just confused the global vs local variable of grades

You don't need this

```
int i = 0;
int grades[];
```

Inside the function readData

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 22;
int grades[SIZE];

void readData() {


    string inFileName = "grades.txt";
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            inFile >> grades[i];
            cout << grades[i] << " ";
        }

        inFile.close(); // CLose input file
    }
    else { //Error message
        cerr << "Can't find input file " << inFileName << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    readData();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: *I don't see any issue* -- See my answer.  There is a big issue.

Comment: I mean to say there was no issue in reading the file .As the OP was "Read data from a file into an array - C++"

Comment: @dev_P Please do add more information if you are not able to get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Your original global array `grades`, of size 22, is replaced by the local array with the same name but of size 0. 
(It is not overwritten, just any code using the variable `grades`, inside the scope that the second one was defined, will read the value of the second `grades` array, as it has a higher precedence.)

Both `inFile >> grades[i];` and `cout << grades[i] << " ";` should return runtime errors as you are reading beyond their size (It appears that you are not using a strict compiler).
[`int grades[i];` would return a compile time error normally as you shouldn't / usually can't initialize a fixed array with a variable]

I think what is happening, instead of your program crashing, is that `grades[i]` is just returning an anonymous instance of a variable with value 0, hence your output.

The simplest fix to your problem would be to just delete `int grades[i]`. 
(Also delete one of the `int i = 0`'s as you don't need that to be defined twice)